# How to apply a blue upper border to my SPAN

Tags: css, master-pages

I have a "Page option" tab inside my web page as follow, and using the firebug it mentioned that the tab uses the "ms-cui-tt-span" class :-

[image]

i added the following CSS but it did not add a blue boarder :-

```
ms-cui-tt-span {
border-top-color: #008CD2 !important;
}
```

Can anyone advise on how to apply a upper border to a span ?

Answer (score 1):

In your code below `ms-cui-tt-span` may be a class applied on the span then

```
.ms-cui-tt-span {
border: 1px solid #008CD2;
}
```

shoul help you achieve the same.

Comment: Here 1px is border-width, solid is border style and the color of the border respectively

Comment: thanks it work, but can i specify to apply this CSS rule, to only tab that have ""Page Option" text, instead of applying it to the whole ms-cui-tt-span class ?

Comment: thanks the html is shown inside my original picture in my question , is that enough ?

Comment: Unfortunately it's not possible with pure css. But you can use Javascript to add another Class to the span and define the border-style only for that class.

Answer (score 1):

Class selectors in your CSS should start with a period (`.`).

So, `ms-cui-tt-span` becomes `.ms-cui-tt-span`.

As an aside, identifier selectors (i.e. those targeting thing by name) should start with a hash (`#`). And only elemental things, that is tags themselves, can be targeted without a prefix - such as in the case of `body`, `form`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
.ms-cui-tt-span {
    border-top: 1px solid #008CD2 !important;
}
```

Comment: He may not apply !important as it may not be required

Comment: thnaks it work, but can i specify to apply this CSS rule, to only tab that have ""Page Option" text, instead of applying it to the whole ms-cui-tt-span class ?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to specify CSS to only tab that have "Page Option" text then try using jQuery

`$(".ms-cui-tt-span:contains('Page Option')").css('border', '1px solid #008CD2')`;

**EDIT**

check this js fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/HSAp5/

Comment: I tried the following script :-$(document).ready(function(){
$(".ms-cui-tt-span:contains('PAGE OPTIONS'))").css('border', '1px solid #008CD2'); . But it did not chnage the boarder, although the scrit do fires well

});

Comment: ans do i need double (..css) as mentioned in your script ? i wrote it as ".CSS('border//code goes here..."

Comment: here is how my final script looks like ater adding !impotant . $(document).ready(function(){


$(".ms-cui-tt-span:contains('Page Option'))").css('border', '1px solid #008CD2 !important');

});   . but it did not chnage the boarder. any idea what might be wrong ?

Comment: text is Page Options rt?

Comment: i hope you have added jquery.min  in your project..?? or can u try like this $("span:contains('Page Option')").css('border', '1px solid #008CD2') btw have you seen the jsfiddle which is working as expected

Comment: ok worked well , $("span:contains('Page Options')").css('border-top', '2px solid #008CD2'). but if the user clicks on the tab the boarder will be removed ?